# Event handling mechanism between ManagedBeans in JSF2?

Tags: events, jsf, jsf-2, dependencies, coupling

Is there a way to decouple ManagedBeans from each other in a way that it is possible to send and receive custom events - probably over the (cool) FacesContext?! I do not want to inject Beans as ManagedProperty, to reduce direct dependencies. Unfortunately @ListenerFor and all that new stuff does only work for components and renderers and seems completely the wrong approach.

Those of you who are familiar with Adobe Flex' event mechanism know what I mean and what I expect from a standardized web UI framework.

Please let me know an elegant way that is included in the JSF specification without the need to implement another framework around.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to decouple ManagedBeans from each other in a way that it is possible to send and receive custom events - probably over the (cool) FacesContext?!

Not without adding the event to a component, and you would have to add it before the Event phase of the JSF lifecycle.

> I do not want to inject Beans as ManagedProperty, to reduce direct dependencies

Just because you are not injecting needed dependencies into your bean, doesn't mean that those dependencies wouldn't exist anyway if you are trying to go with an event driven model.  At least by injecting the dependencies you explicitly declare what the managed bean depends on.  This seems like a much more maintainable solution than what you are proposing.

> Those of you who are familiar with Adobe Flex' event mechanism know what I mean and what I expect from a standardized web UI framework.

You expect a desktop based event driven model in a web application framework?  This is apples to oranges.  Adobe Flex is a Rich Internet Application that behaves like a desktop application while communicating with outside web services.  JSF is a web application framework standard for web based components powered by javascript and ajax, with reusable server components and a server lifecycle which includes an event phase for components.

> Please let me know an elegant way that is included in the JSF specification without the need to implement another framework around.

Your language implies that you do not find JSF elegant and that you are actively trying to make it something that it is not.  Please do not do this, you will create a nightmare for yourself and anybody who has to maintain your application.

JSF requires a different way of thinking about web application development than what you are used to.  If you find it this unpalatable then I suggest abandoning it for a web application framework that fits your comfortability level.  You mentioned Flex, there is also Silverlight with .NET.